# Certificate pathing erors

Tags: openssl

I'm not really sure where my problem is at and am looking for any general advice. I am hosting a server off an arduino that hosts on a private network 192.168.x.x. I can access the website fine and all I want to do is scrape the text on the site "Hello from ESP8266!", however no matter which method I try to use, there is always some error related to the certificate when I try to input the url to scrape from, when I use a normal url everything works fine.

Ive spent the past few days trying to figure out the certificate process and finally added one to my root certification authorities that makes it so no warnings occur when I visit the page. I create the certificate using openssl with the command

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -nodes -keyout finalkey.pem -new -out finalcert.crt -config test.cnf -sha256 -days 3650
```

and the cnf file

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = US
ST = VA
L = SomeCity
O = MyCompany
OU = MyDivision
CN = localhost
[v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = DNS:localhost,IP:192.168.x.x,IP:127.0.0.1
```

Since I can scrape from any other website, I'm sure my certificate process is erroneous, but I've tried dozens of suggested methods already and this is the closest ive been able to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem resided in the software I was using, RapidMiner. I did not specify the cert through the software so it had problems accessing the site.